# Longest common subsequence solution reconstruction during DP is wrong

Tags: dynamic-programming, python

I've implemented longest common substring in `python`. I know the usual way to reconstruct the path. But, I am reading my algorithm many times, I don't understand why it doesn't work for some test-cases. I am trying to construct the solution while the longest path is being made through dynamic programming.

```python
def lcs(s1, s2):
    n = len(s1)
    m = len(s2)
    
    trow = [0] * (m+1)
    table = [trow] * (n+1)
    
    srow = [""] * (m+1)
    solution = [srow] * (n+1)
    
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, m+1):
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:                
                table[i][j] = table[i-1][j-1] + 1
                
                # Adding this character to the solution
                solution[i][j] = solution[i-1][j-1] + s1[i-1]
            
            elif table[i][j-1] > table[i-1][j]:
                table[i][j] = table[i][j-1]
                
                # Choosing the solution related to the longer path
                solution[i][j] = solution[i][j-1] 
                
            else:
                table[i][j] = table[i-1][j]
                
                # Choosing the solution related to the longer path
                solution[i][j] = solution[i-1][j] 
    
    return solution[n-1][m-1]
```

```
lcs('amin', 'kahmjiknln')
# Returns 'amin'

lcs('amin', 'aaaakahmjiknln')
# Returns 'aaaaamin'
```

Comment: Debugging or diagnosing problems with your code is off-topic here.  We're not a coding site.  Questions about algorithms can be on-topic, but we discourage questions written in code, as not everyone understands Python, and our focus is on the algorithm not on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets deal with the issues one at a time, since there are a few of them.

### Problem 1

Take a look at those lines of code:

```py
trow = [0] * (m+1)
table = [trow] * (n+1)
    
srow = [""] * (m+1)
solution = [srow] * (n+1)
```

The problem with this code, is that the *same* list is being placed a few times. This means, that every list in $table$ must be all identical to $trow$ **at all times.** By changing one of the values in there, it will change all of them. For example, if $m=n=1$, then `table == [[0,0],[0,0]]`. Now, assume we somehow did this update: `table[0][1] = 9`. Then, we will have `table == [[0, 9], [0, 9]]` since $table$ contains the *same* list *twice*. This is essentially caused because lists are just pointers, and thus if you just copy the value in them it will just copy the pointer. A similar behavior can be seen in this code:

```py
a = 5 # a == 5
b = a # a == 5, b == 5
b = 10 # a == 5, b == 10

A = [0, 1] # A == [0, 1]
B = A # A == [0, 1], B == [0, 1], A is B
B[0] = 9 # A == [9, 1], B == [9, 1], A is B
```

Here, the same thing happened: $a$ is not a list and therefore was copied as expected, but $A$ is a list and thus only the pointer to it was copied to $B$. A change in $B$ changed $A$ as well.

Back to your question. How to fix it, you ask? Like so:

```py
table = [[0 for _ in range(m + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]

solution = [["" for _ in range(m + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]
```

### Problem 2

You have a slight problem with the indices. Since $solution$ is an $(n+1)$-by-$(m+1)$ matrix, you want `solution[n][m]` instead of `solution[n - 1][m - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Programming questions are off-topic here.
Anyway your matrices `table` and `solution` are not properly initialized as they contain references to the same objects. Try:

```python
    table = [[0]*(m+1) for j in range(n+1)]
    solution = [ ["" for i in range(m+1)] for j in range(n+1) ]
```

Moreover, the returned string should be `solution[n][m]` and not `solution[n-1][m-1]`.